# React / Redux: Action creator does not work with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the following action creator in my React/Redux application, and I am trying to fetch some data. For this I am using superagent & redux-thunk. However, although the function is called (It does log `(1) Called`)it doesn't ever go into the thunk-part, so `(2) Called` is never printed out in the console.

```
export function fetchPosts () { //fetches headline, calls dispatchHeadline to dispatch the newly fetched headline
    console.log("(1) Called");
    return (dispatch) => {

        console.log("(2) Called");
        let url = "http://innovation-insight.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
        let blogposts = [];

        Request.get(url).then((response) =>{
            console.log("response3000:");
            console.log(response);

        //   for(var i=0; i< response.body.length; i++)
        //   {
        //     blogposts.push(response.body[i]);
        //     console.log(blogposts[i].title.rendered);
        //   }

        let currentPost = response.body[0];
        dispatch(dispatchPosts(currentPost));
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling fetchPosts() ? Have you provided redux-thunk as a middleware in your redux store?

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: No, haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up your store?